# PHP and InfowWindows

Tags: php, google-maps-markers

```
    while($DNB->fetch()){
?>
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: <?php echo $businessname ?>});
     var point  = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ?>, <?php echo $lon ?>);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map:map});
     google.maps.even
```

t.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});

When I run the above code the map does not show.  However, when I replace the php tags with just "blah" it works. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the PHP snippets.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<?php echo $businessname ?>"});
var point  = new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $lat ?>", "<?php echo $lon ?>");
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map:map});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
```

Comment: Actually, if $lat and $lon are valid floats you won't need quotes around them, but you can try it both ways and see what works.

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes around the $lat and $lon snippets?

Comment: The markers show but the InfoWindow only shows for one marker.

Comment: Any reasons why I am getting multiple markers but only one info window?

Comment: Could you add the rest of the loop code in your original post?